# Why am I not getting any package from the Influxdb repository?

Tags: repository

I would like to install Influxdb via a repo, not by [installing manually each release](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/install/?t=Linux), so I tried to add a repo for it, as I used to do with Influxdb v1 (I just updated my server after a long while).

I followed the instructions [provided](https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/) but "apt list influx*" gave no results:

```
# apt list influx*
Listing... Done
```

so I adapted it to ubuntu, by browsing the repo myself, so I after cleaning up things I repeated except by:

- changing from "-archive_compat" to "-archive", as recommended,
- skipping verification of the signature because I couldn't find the value to compare the "-archive" against
- change from debian to ubuntu

  ```
  wget -q https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive.key
  cat influxdata-archive.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive.gpg > /dev/null
  echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu jammy stable' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list
  ```

and "apt update"

Now I get in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list:

deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu jammy stable

however the same result:

```
# apt list influx*
Listing... Done
```

If I check manually https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/stable/binary-amd64/Packages I find there are packages inside it!

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The instructions say for Ubuntu to add the repo `https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main` I don't think the repo you added for Ubuntu actually exists. Notice what you checked has "dists" in the URL, the repo you added doesn't.

Comment: @OrganicMarble if I manually browse the link I provided I can find packages

Comment: Yeah but the link is not the same as the repo you added. It has "dists" in it after *ubuntu* What you added doesn't.

Comment: Instructions here https://i.imgur.com/QTTyvT0.png

Comment: @OrganicMarble that would've been better posted as **an answer** quoting the instructions rather than a screenshot.  (Note I wrote an answer as such)

Comment: @ThomasWard roger that, but I don't post answers if I haven't validated them myself, and I can't do that for this one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I tried it before switching to "ubuntu", it didn' t change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command lines I executed were correct, but somehow the

```
apt list influx*
```

I used to find all version was the culprit: if I run

```
apt list influxdb*
```

I get all packages I expect, both the 1.x and the 2.x versions. Somehow truncating influxdb doesn't work the same way as, for example, "apt nan*" which gives me nano, nanopolish and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What you added is NOT the proper URL for your repository.  **NOWHERE** in the instructions did it say to replace `debian` or `stable` with `ubuntu` and the codename of your Ubuntu version.

The instructions from the repository page itself in question (https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu/) explicitly state:

> **DEB Repo**
>
> For DEB-based platforms (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian):
>
> ```
> wget -q https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive_compat.key
> echo '393e8779c89ac8d958f81f942f9ad7fb82a25e133faddaf92e15b16e6ac9ce4c influxdata-archive_compat.key' | sha256sum -c && cat influxdata-archive_compat.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg > /dev/null
> echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/influxdata-archive_compat.gpg] https://repos.influxdata.com/debian stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/influxdata.list
> ```

Because you did not follow these instructions and use the correct repository URL, you are not actually *looking* at the proper repository.  Ubuntu and Debian, per the Influx Data page, both use the debian root directory of stable for the packages.  **Follow the instructions set by the repository** and you should be able to see the packages.

Comment: Actually I think the first time I tried it blindly before realising I was being directed to Debian, and it didn't work. I'll try again to be sure and I'll report back

Comment: The commands they suggest presents the same issue.